# Azure pipeline not working for production

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

I want to deploy 3 Service Bus Resources using the azure pipeline.

1. amit-dev - for dev environment.
2. amit-tst - for the test environment.
3. amit-prd - for PRD environment

test and dev don't need approval, but prd deployment needs approval.

my pipeline is able to deploy dev and test resource without any problem, It asks for approval when it comes to prd deployment, But then it stops with   error message :

```
Creating deployment parameters.
##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern
Finishing: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment
```

Here is my pipeline code.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
      - release/*
      - feature/*
      - bug-fix/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: 'DevDeployStage'
    dependsOn: BuildStage
    condition: and(succeeded('BuildStage'), contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/main'))
    variables:
    - group: common-kv-dev
    - group: common-dp-dev
    displayName: 'DevDeployStage'
    jobs: 
      - job:  DevDeployStageJob
        steps:
          - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
            inputs:
                deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
                azureResourceManagerConnection: 'conn-to-RG'
                subscriptionId: '7777777-4444-4444-4444-222222222222'
                action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
                resourceGroupName: 'MY_RG'
                location: 'East US'
                templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
                csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/template.json'
                csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/parameters.json'
                overrideParameters: '-namespaces_amitbus_name amit-dev'
                deploymentMode: 'Incremental'

  - stage: 'tstDeployStage'
    dependsOn: BuildStage
    condition: and(succeeded('BuildStage'), contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/main'))
    variables:
    - group: common-kv-dev
    - group: common-dp-dev
    displayName: 'tstDeployStage'
    jobs: 
      - job:  tstDeployStageJob
        steps:
          - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
            inputs:
                deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
                azureResourceManagerConnection: 'conn-to-RG'
                subscriptionId: '7777777-4444-4444-4444-222222222222'
                action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
                resourceGroupName: 'MY_RG'
                location: 'East US'
                templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
                csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/template.json'
                csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/parameters.json'
                overrideParameters: '-namespaces_amitbus_name amit-tst'
                deploymentMode: 'Incremental'

  - stage: 'PrdDeployStage'
    dependsOn: BuildStage
    condition: and(succeeded('BuildStage'), contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/main'))
    variables:
    - group: common-kv-dev
    - group: common-dp-dev
    displayName: 'PrdDeployStage'
    jobs: 
      - deployment: PrdDeployStageJobDeploment
        displayName: 'PrdDeployStageJob'
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        environment: production
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
                  inputs:
                    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
                    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'conn-to-RG'
                    subscriptionId: '7777777-4444-4444-4444-222222222222'
                    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
                    resourceGroupName: 'MY_RG'
                    location: 'East US'
                    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
                    csmFile: 'template.json'
                    csmParametersFile: 'parameters.json'
                    overrideParameters: '-namespaces_amitbus_name amit-prd'
                    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

I fail to understand why prd deployment is giving errors, whereas the same lines of code work for test and dev environments without any issues.

Comment: This is why you should use templates: Your "prd" stage is clearly using different values for `csmFile` and `csmParametersFile`. This has nothing to do with approvals.

Comment: No that is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job and deployments are different in nature. By default, job will download the repo but deployment will not. Just mentioned checkout: self in deployment and it fixed my issue.